# Search and retrieve images from Google based on G-Sheet value

Tags: google-sheets, google-image-search

I'm trying to find a way to find and download automatically images from google images of a lot of products based on their unique code.

This is an example:

Product Code: 976395893
First image I find if i search it on G-Images that I'd like to download locally: https://www.farmae.it/media/catalog/product/import/206984.jpg?optimize=medium&fit=bounds&height=700&width=700&canvas=700:700

Thanks in advance for the support!!!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `This is an example:`. Can I ask you about the detail of both your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.